# Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected

Tags: node.js

I'm getting an error doing a very basic GET request using the [request module](https://github.com/request/request).

Here's my code:

```
var request = require('request');
var url = 'http://www.bigassfans.com/case-studies/delphine-restaurant/';

request({
    url : url,
    headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.94 Safari/537.36'
    }
}, function(error, response, html){
        console.log(response.statusCode);
        console.log(response.headers);
});
```

Here's my error messages:

> (node:75952) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 pipe listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
>
> (node:75952) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 pipe listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'statusCode' of undefined
>
> ```
> at Request._callback (/foo/foo.js:10:29)
> at self.callback (/foo/node_modules/request/request.js:200:22)
> at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
> at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
> at Redirect.onResponse (/foo/node_modules/request/lib/redirect.js:94:13)
> at Request.onRequestResponse (/foo/node_modules/request/request.js:908:22)
> at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
> at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:7)
> at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (_http_client.js:469:21)
> at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:105:23)
> ```

What's going on? Is this a bug in the request module or is something wrong with my code?

Comment: Well it looks like the Error is being thrown because the response argument in your callback is undefined and you are looking for `response.statusCode` As far as the possible memory leak, are you using the event emitter in your application ?

Comment: The error you are getting says it cannot read property statusCode of undefined which means *response* variable is not defined. Add console.log(error) above console.log(response.statusCode); to see if there's any error

Comment: I think the library has an issue with that specific url. You should not get these '11 pipe listeners added'..., maybe something goes wrong while redirecting? Try open an issue on git.

Comment: That page keeps redirecting to itself unless you sent along the `bas_country` cookie it sets.

Comment: @robertklep You are right. I saw the page was redirecting to itself but didn't realize it was cookie-based. The weird thing is it doesn't do that to a regular Chrome browser (at least, not that I can see in the Network panel of Chrome dev tools). And when I used Chrome's user agent in node/request, the server does this. So what is it in node/request that is generating a different type of HTTP request than Chrome that would trigger such a response from the server?

Comment: @tinkerr Chrome (or any regular browser) will accept the cookie and send it along the next request, stopping the redirect loop. So you need to make sure that `request` will handle cookies too (check out the [`jar` option](https://github.com/request/request)).

Comment: @robertklep That makes sense. Enabling cookies fixes it. Thanks!